# Getting the same screen when calling startActivity()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, start-activity

I'm programming an android app with Android Studio where Imagebutton opens a new screen so that the user can proceed to the next step. Imagebutton is working and new screen opens, but it isn't opening second activity but the same one.

I'm new to android and java programming, so please tell me if other codes are necessary for solving the problem and sorry if I shared unnecessary code.

I have created startActivity with intent.

Here are my current codes of MainActivity java-file and AndroidManifest xml-file:

> MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TextView mTextMessage;

  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

      switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.navigation_home:
          mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
          return true;

        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
          mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
          return true;

        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
          mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    final ImageButton imgButton = findViewById(R.id.simpleImageViewHowdoglearnspackage);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
      }

    });
  }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.mobidogi">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".SecondActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_second" />
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Just a guess: You copy/pasted `onCreate` from `MainActivity` into `SecondActivity` and forget to change `R.layout.activity_main` to `R.layout.activity_second` in the `setContentView`.

Comment: yep the code is solid. I guess @tobltobs is right.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working correctly.